# Prevent a text field within a portal from being truncated, filtering portal contents to display in another layout

Tags: filemaker

I am already using Filemaker Pro 10, I have two questions:

1. I have a text field in a portal, and whenever I am entering values like "B12C45" in it, it works well, but when the string is longer like "BC12F42, B45z87" it doesn't show whole the strings and omits the letters from it. what Can I do?
2. My second question is that: I have a portal in a layout, in this portal every row has an id sometimes the id is repeated in other rows but the value of another field called Position is changing. Now I want to have those rows of this portal which have the same id in another layout. I have tried using scripts for it, but scripts don't work well in this case, and they are entering whole the portal in the new layout not the parts I want . How can I write a script which does this?

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question there are many ways you could display more data in a field and the best one will depend on the particular implementation in your database.  There are three main ways to solve this problem: field-size adjustments, text-size adjustments and programming adjustments to dynamically change the text-size.

Field-size adjustments include:

1. Making the field longer
2. Using the autosizing aspect of a field so that as the window grows, so does the field

Text-size adjustments include:

1. Making the font size for that field smaller.
2. Setting the font style for that field to condensed.

Programatically, though, three things stand out to me as possibilities.  I like the third one the best for most of my solutions:

1. Set the tooltip for the field to "Self" (without the quotes).  A user can see the entire contents of the field by hovering the mouse over the field.
2. In "Define Database" set the field's calculated value to: "TextStyleAdd(self;Condense)" (without the quotes) and make certain that "Do not replace existing value of field" is turned off
3. Use Conditional formatting to add the Condense style or use a smaller font when the number of the characters in the field gets long.

The steps for using conditional formatting are as follows:

1. In layout mode select the field and select 'Conditional Formatting...' from the pop-up menu
2. Add a new condition
3. Change the condition to 'Formula is'
4. In the text field enter "Length(Self) > 8" (without the quotes)
5. Press the "More Formatting..." button
6. Select "Condense" as the Style from the text

You can add multiple conditions, so you might have "Condense" only for Length(Self) > 8 and another condition for Length(Self) > 16 where you set both "Condense" and reduce the Font Size.




As for your second question, I'm not able to get a picture of what you're trying to do from the question you asked.  You might be able do the following in a script:
    Go to Related Record [the portal relationship]
    Sort Records [by ID]

And then use a summary field (Count of ID) to determine how many of each ID you have.

If you clarified what you were trying to do, gave more information about your tables and table occurrences, we might be able to provide a better answer for this instance.